# $C(X)$ is a locally convex space - exercise 4.1.5. from Conway's Functional Analysis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

The author defines locally convex sets as a TVS whose topology is defined by a family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}$ such that $\bigcap_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \{x\ |\ p(x) = 0\} = \{0\}$. A bit later he gives the following example.

**1. 5. Example** Let $X$ be completely regular and let $C(X) =$ all continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{F}$. If $K$ is a compact subset of $X$, define $p_K (f) = \sup \{|f(x)|\ |\ x \in K\}$. Then $\{p_K\ |\ \textrm{$K$ compact in $X$}\}$ is a family of seminorms that makes $C(X)$ into a LCS.

I don't see how the assumption of complete regularity is used in this example. If we want to prove that the above TVS is LCS, we just need to prove that for every nonzero function $f \in C(X)$ there exists some compact subset $K \subseteq X$ such that $p_K (f) \neq 0$. Since $f$ is nonzero, there has to exist a point $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$. But then we can just take $K = \{x_0\}$ because singletons are compact in any topology.

Clearly, I am missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, the_dude. One does not need any properties of $X$ to get this locally convex topology *of uniform convergence on compact sets*. @geetha290krm What is *the standard topology* on $C(X)$? Do you mean the *compact-open-topology*?

Comment: The topology of uniform convergence on compact sets  has nice properties only when  $X$ has some regularity properties.  That must be why Conway assumes that $X$ is completely regular.

Comment: I agree with @geetha290krm ... complete regularity is not needed for this examlpe, but will come up later for other things involving the space $C(X)$.  For example, it $X$ is completely regular, then $C(X)$ separates points of $X$.  There are examples of  (not completely  regular) spaces $X$ such that the only elements of $C(X)$ are the constants.